# Celery keeps creating rabbitmq queues, pilling all over

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery

Using celery (3.1.8 + ) with django 1.6
all tasks are defined to ignore results (is this the correct syntax?)

```
@shared_task(ignore_result=True)
def somefunc():
   pass
```

When I look at the rabbitmq queues I see more and more queues created by celery with names like:

> > 19926fa9965e40c19ed9640c2b42ce1e

and contain one message (similar to the following):

> correlation_id:   19926fa9-965e-40c1-9ed9-640c2b42ce1e priority:  0
>   delivery_mode:    2 headers:   content_encoding:  binary
>   content_type: application/x-python-serialize Payload 118 bytes
>   Encoding: base64
>   gAJ9cQEoVQZzdGF0dXNxAlUHU1VDQ0VTU3EDVQl0cmFjZWJhY2txBE5VBnJlc3VsdHEFTlUHdGFza19pZHEGVSQxOTkyNmZhOS05NjVlLTQwYzEtOWVkOS02
>   NDBjMmI0MmNlMWVxB1UIY2hpbGRyZW5xCF11Lg==

If I set celery to "always eager" mode then the problem is solved, but this is obviously not a good solution for a production server.

Any Clues? Is this connected to the ignore_result option? and there is some missing task somewhere? something else?

Thanks for the help

Comment: What it's the problem exactly? `19926fa9965e40c19ed9640c2b42ce1e` seems to me a task id, so you're just seeing the tasks transmitted by rabbitmq.

Comment: @SébastienDeprez It sounds like each message is getting its own queue, which is not the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how django or your code defines the `@shared_task` decorator, but have you tried explicitly setting the queue within it?

```
@shared_task(ignore_results=True, queue="myexamplequeue")
```

This would apply the message to the `myexamplequeue` whenever you call `.delay()` or `.apply_async()` on `somefunc`.

Comment: Should it be ignore_result. or ignore_results? I noticed that my code mixed up with both versions

Comment: Oh, I missed that. It should be `ignore_result`. See the [docs on tasks](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html).