# Rabbitmq message queues pile up untill system crash (all queues are "ready")

Tags: django, memory-leaks, rabbitmq, celery

I have a simple Raspberry pi + Django + Celery + Rabbitmq setup that I use to send and receive data from Xbee radios while users interact with the web app.

For the life of me I cant get Rabbitmq (or celery?) under control where after only a single day (sometimes a little longer) the whole system crashes due to some kind of memory leak.

What I am suspecting is that the queues are piling up and never being removed.

Heres a picture of what I see after only a few minutes of run time:
[image]

Seems that all of the queues are in the "ready" state.

What's strange is that it would appear that the workers do in fact receive the message and run the task.

The task is very small and shouldn't take longer than 1 second.
I have verified the tasks do execute to the last line and should be returning ok.

I'm no expert and have no clue what I'm actually looking at so I'm unsure if that is normal behavior and my issue lies elsewhere?

I have everything set to run as daemonized, however even when running in development modes I get same results.

I have spent the last four hours debugging with Google search and found it was taking me in circles and I was not finding clarity.

[CONFIGS AND CODE]

in /ect/default/celeryd I have set the following:

```
CELERY_APP="MyApp"
CELERYD_NODES="w1"

# Python interpreter from environment.
ENV_PYTHON="/home/pi/.virtualenvs/myappenv/bin/python"

# Where to chdir at start.
CELERYD_CHDIR="/home/pi/django_projects/MyApp"

# Virtual Environment Setup
ENV_MY="/home/pi/.virtualenvs/myappenv"
CELERYD="$ENV_MY/bin/celeryd"
CELERYD_MULTI="$ENV_PYTHON $CELERYD_CHDIR/manage.py celeryd_multi"
CELERYCTL="$ENV_MY/bin/celeryctl"

CELERYD_OPTS="--app=MyApp --concurrency=1 --loglevel=FATAL"

CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%n.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%n.pid"

CELERYD_USER="celery"
CELERYD_GROUP="celery"
```

tasks.py

```
@celery.task
def sendStatus(modelContext, ignore_result=True, *args,  **kwargs):
    node = modelContext#EndNodes.objects.get(node_addr_lg=node_addr_lg)
    #check age of message and proceed to send status update if it is fresh, otherwise we'll skip it
    if not current_task.request.eta == None:
        now_date = datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=None) #the time now
        eta_date = dateutil.parser.parse(current_task.request.eta).replace(tzinfo=None)#the time this was supposed to run, remove timezone from message eta datetime
        delta_seconds = (now_date - eta_date).total_seconds()#seconds from when this task was supposed to run
        if delta_seconds >= node.status_timeout:#if the message was queued more than delta_seconds ago this message is too old to process
            return
    #now that we know the message is fresh we can proceed to process the contents and send status to xbee
    hostname = current_task.request.hostname #the name/key in the schedule that might have related xbee sessions

    app = Celery('app')#create a new instance of app (because documented methods didnt work)

    i = app.control.inspect()
    scheduled_tasks = i.scheduled()#the schedule of tasks in the queue

    for task in scheduled_tasks[hostname]:#iterate through each task
        xbee_session = ast.literal_eval(task['request']['kwargs'])#the request data in the message (converts unicode to dict)
        if xbee_session['xbee_addr'] == node.node_addr_lg:#get any session data for this device that we may have set from model's save override
            if xbee_session['type'] == 'STAT':#because we are responding with status update we look for status sessions
                app.control.revoke(task['request']['id'], terminate=True)#revoke this task because it is redundant and we are sending update now

    page_mode = chr(node.page_mode)#the paging mode to set on the remote device
    xbee_global.tx(dest_addr_long=bytearray.fromhex(node.node_addr_lg),
                   frame_id='A',
                   dest_addr='\xFF\xFE',
                   data=page_mode)
```

celery splash:

```
 -------------- celery@raspberrypi v3.1.23 (Cipater)
---- **** -----
--- * ***  * -- Linux-4.4.11-v7+-armv7l-with-debian-8.0
-- * - **** ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         MyApp:0x762efe10
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     amqp://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 1 (prefork)
-- ******* ----
--- ***** ----- [queues]
 -------------- .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . MyApp.celery.debug_task
  . clone_app.tasks.nodeInterval
  . clone_app.tasks.nodePoll
  . clone_app.tasks.nodeState
  . clone_app.tasks.resetNetwork
  . clone_app.tasks.sendData
  . clone_app.tasks.sendStatus

[2016-10-11 03:41:12,863: WARNING/Worker-1] Got signal worker_process_init for task id None
[2016-10-11 03:41:12,913: WARNING/Worker-1] JUST OPENED
[2016-10-11 03:41:12,915: WARNING/Worker-1] /dev/ttyUSB0
[2016-10-11 03:41:12,948: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//
[2016-10-11 03:41:13,101: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2016-10-11 03:41:14,206: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2016-10-11 03:41:14,341: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@raspberrypi ready.
[2016-10-11 03:41:16,223: WARNING/Worker-1] RAW DATA
[2016-10-11 03:41:16,225: WARNING/Worker-1] {'source_addr_long': '\x00\x13\xa2\x00@\x89\xe9\xd7', 'rf_data': '...^%:STAT:`', 'source_addr': '[*', 'id': 'rx', 'options': '\x01'}
[2016-10-11 03:41:16,458: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: clone_app.tasks.sendStatus[6e1a74ec-dca5-495f-a4fa-906a5c657b26] eta:[2016-10-11 03:41:17.307421+00:00]
```

I can provide additional details if required!!
And thank you for any help resolving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, almost immedietly after posting my question I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24918581/3961748) and it has completely resolved my issue.

As I expected ignore_result=True was required, I just was not sure where it belonged.

Now I see no queues except maybe for the instant a worker is running a task. :)

---

Here's the change in tasks.py:

```
#From
@celery.task
def sendStatus(modelContext, ignore_result=True, *args,  **kwargs):
    #Some code here

#To
@celery.task(ignore_result=True)
def sendStatus(modelContext, *args,  **kwargs):
    #Some code here
```